# Is it possible to programming/generate a file for 3D printable object?

Tags: php, printing, 3d

I want to know if is it possible to generate with a PHP library or C/C++ or an another language a 3D object printable. Like the .stl files.

Comment: PHP, C and C++ and very different languages. Specify one and add the language tag.

Comment: You can google STL format spec and I'm pretty sure that you can find opensource software with parses or you can write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write your own `.stl` ASCII files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#ASCII_STL

`.stl` files will always begin and end with a `solid` tag containing any number of `facets`.

Each `facet` will have a `normal` property and contain an `outer loop` tag which will hold your `vertex`s.

The `facet`'s `normal` property and the `vertex`s use space separated `float`s.

All this is easily accomplished in C++, C, or PHP.

You can see an example of a simple cube here: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/stla/stla.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://packagist.org/packages/php3d/stl. It lets you manipulate STL files - I wrote it a few weeks back, and is still experimental, but you might find it useful.

This one here lets you convert STL files to G-Code or SVG:
https://packagist.org/packages/php3d/stlslice

Again, experimental, but you can easily change the code to suit your needs.